# MongoDB drop collection and insert new data transactionally

Tags: mongodb

I'm thinking of trying mongoDb for a project I'm working on but don't have too much experience with it.

I'm wondering if it's possible to, in a transaction, drop the current collection, insert all the new data in a collection with the same name, then commit the transaction. While the old data is still available during the fill up with new data and then right after the transaction is commited the new data will be used.

Also might this create performance issues?

Comment: You could also rename a collection. Collections are automatically created at insert if they don't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @WernfriedDomscheit. I looked into it and for my use case I think loading in the new data in a separate temporary collection and then just renaming the temporary collection to the actual collection naem and set the drop flag to true should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a collection is not allowed in a transaction: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#restricted-operations

Comment: Ok I see, but running db.user.remove({}) and then inserting while in the transaction should work with the desired behaviour?